# Do I need more PSU power or new GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I recently started to play Portal 2 on my Windows 7 PC and after some time game just exits.
Now I thought there was some issue with the game or my drivers, so I updated to the latest drivers for my card and run other games - same result, after some time games just exit and I'm on desktop.

### My PC's specs:

- OS: Windows 7 (32bit)
- Motherboard: Asus M5A99X EVO
- GPU: AMD Phenom II x6 1090T
- GPU: Asus GeForce 9800 GTX+
- PSU: OCZ ModXstream-pro 600W
- RAM: 2 x Kingston 4GB DDR3 1600 (CL9)
- HDD: 2 x HDD
- USB: 1 mouse, 1 keyboard, 1 external hdd, 1 usb flash (all running USB 2)

On a side note: I know I don't use 8GB ram, but that's till my DVD-drive gets shiped then I install 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. According to specs `+12V1: 25A, +12V2: 25A` your PSU can handle alot more power-eating GPU
2. Updating drivers doesn't require more power for GPU
3. Check memory (memtest), VCard (Video Memory stress Test)
4. Usual Windows procedures

   - check event-log
   - scandisk
   - defrag

Answer (score 1):

It depends, you'll need to find the rated wattage on the +12V rail since your CPU, Mobo, and GPU depend on that same rail. This should be found on the PSU itself (on a sticker).

For example, 600W power supply doesn't mean anything by itself, you want to make sure that it's +12V rail can deliver enough power to your parts. There are other rails like the 6V, 3.3V rail, etc, for your other peripherals. So all the wattage provided by all rails added together will be 600W. If the +12V rail is too low, you may not have enough power to provide to all devices.

Your PSU can also degrade over time, meaning that these rails will not support as much power as it could when you first bought it. So if it's old, your PSU could be failing.

For now, you seem to have enough power, since both your CPU and your GPU aren't as intensive has higher powered devices.

If your OS freezes and your computer restarts, then there's not enough power to your CPU.
If your game freezes and closes, it could mean many things such as a virus, the game itself, or your CPU not getting enough power. But to me, 600W is sufficient.

Comment: Hmm, based to all internet pc-power calculators i should have enough power as you say. i have +12V1 and +12V2 - max combined power 504W on sticker. Tho i dunno what that means :)

Comment: Yeah, that is plenty of power. It looks like your PSU has a dual-rail, meaning that the degradation is much slower. I would check for new drivers for your GPUs, etc.

Comment: I don't see any reason that a power issue would just cause the GAME TO EXIT regardless.  If it's not causing any other strange behavior, I'd look at the game (or your graphics settings or drivers or something related).  If you're drawing too much power, things should be breaking catastrophically.